# Search and save images from google images in iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4

In my app I need to search images from google images for a particular word.

for example, i want to search image for `Earth`.

How to search images from Google Images and save selected images in documents directory?

Is there any API that can I use? Or any other way to do it?

Comment: hey @Meghan, can u please guide me, how did u manage all this stuff. I am having the same problem as you mentioned. Please guide me a way out because I am new iOS platform, Please do me favor.

Comment: You can use @Nick Weaver's answer and You can go with http://stackoverflow.com/a/6109653/566431 also. It uses queue for downloading images.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Google API

[Google Image Search API / JSON Developer's Guide](http://code.google.com/apis/imagesearch/v1/jsondevguide.html).

You will have to display the images yourself as the result is a json response. However this will give you maximum control. The result will contain a thumbnail URL which you can use to show the preview.

### Downloading images

Downloading images can be done in many ways:

- [URL Loading System Programming Guide / Using NSURLConnection](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001836-BAJEAIEE)
- [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/)
- [NSData class method dataWithContentsOfURL](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000172-BBCGJEAC) and usage of the UIImage method [imageWithData:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006890-CH3-SW13)

The use of the Google API does only work under certain circumstances such as

"*Applications that use this interface must abide by all existing Terms of Service. Most importantly, you must correctly identify yourself in your requests.*"

### Saving Images

After receiving the results you can save the image to disk with:

```
NSString *aFileName = @"myImage.jpg";
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; 
NSString *path = [documentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:aFileName];

[myImageAsData writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
```

alternatively if you've got the image as **UIImage** already:

```
NSData *myImageAsData = [NSData dataWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(anImage)];
[myImageAsData writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
```

Comment: Thanks for Links. Through Google API I got NSArray of URLs (of images) in - (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection Method. And then fetching images in NSData (using NSData* imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];) in loop.  It works but taking too much time.  What can be done?

Comment: @Meghan I think this is a different problem, worth a different question.

Comment: hi @NickWeaver first of all thanks to the such good documents. I would request you if you have done the same, then can u please share the code. Because I am in real trouble I been working on the same from last 10 days and unable to fetch the desired result. Please help me out

Comment: @Deepak Khiwani Here's a gist for you: [Gist](https://gist.github.com/nickyEnjoysWoogoo/5458128). The JSON API is pretty straight forward to use.

Comment: @NickWeaver thank you for your support but I wanted to get one image from multiple images and that selected image then to be used in the application. For deep details I would request you to look at the link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16206727/accessing-google-images-searching-and-saving-within-the-application

Comment: @Deepak Khiwani you should really look at the code. The first URL requested is a search term "fuzzy monkey" only percent escaped. The request returns a LIST in a json format, in the gist it only extracts the first hit of the list. Then it downloads that image and saves it on the device.

Answer (score 3):

First, you want the Google Image Search API. http://code.google.com/apis/imagesearch/

Next, if you're cool with only targeting iOS 4.0 and later, you can use Grand Central Dispatch and the very useful sycnhronous data APIs included in iOS. Specifically, I'm thinking of [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:]. This will block the thread until it downloads the whole image, so **don't run it on the main thread**. Fortunately, GCD lets you throw stuff on a background thread with ease. So your code will probably look something like this:

```
dispatch_queue_t NetworkQueue = dispatch_queue_create("NetworkQueue", 0);

dispatch_async(NetworkQueue,^{
    NSData* imageResultsData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:
    [NSURL urlWithString:@"https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/images?some_images_query_here"];
   //do something with that data
   //let's say you unpacked it into an NSArray of NSURLs
   for(NSURL* url in myImageArray) {
        dispatch_async(NetworkQueue,^{
            NSData* imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
            [imageData writeToFile:file_name_here atomically:YES];
        });
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Google Image Search is not working:

> "The Google Image Search API has been officially deprecated as of May
>   26, 2011. It will continue to work as per our deprecation policy, but
>   the number of requests you may make per day may be limited. We
>   encourage you to use the Custom Search API, which now supports image
>   search."

Here is the link to the [Custom Search API](https://developers.google.com/custom-search)